# Averaging temperatures over time on multiple dates

Tags: r, data.table, temperature

I have a device that measures temperature at 10sec intervals and is worn by a subject for a number of days.  I want to average the temperatures every 30 seconds.  My data set can be missing data points (from an individual 10sec data point missing to a block of several hours if device accidently turned off).  The code I have written will average the temperatures over 30 seconds eg 10.30.00 to 10.30.30 but doesn't separate by date so I end up with an average for the one time block over all dates.  I have added an example of the data below (same times over 3 days) and the converted table and output. The code I am using is below

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Yhw.png)

[data as table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRC6v.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTjwy.png)

```
df_sum <- df[, c('Hour', 'Minute', 'Second') := .(data.table::hour(datetime), minute(datetime),
second (datetime))][, second_Cut := cut(Second, breaks = c(0,30,60), include.lowest = T)
][, .(Avg = mean(CorTemp)), .(Hour, Minute, second_Cut)]
```

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: I apologise for getting this wrong and for adding the images - this was the first question I have posted and could not work out how to upload the data csv files, output etc (kept getting an error message).  I am sorry.

Comment: @JMc  you can post your data by `dput(your data.frame)` if the data.frame is not big. or you just post several rows like this `dput(head(your data.frame, n = 20))`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
# generate random sample
tmp = seq(as.POSIXct("2023-03-05 12:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2023-03-05 12:12:00"),by="sec")
df = data.table(datetime=tmp,TEMP=37+rnorm(length(tmp),sd = 2))
# this is what you what
res= df[,
        .(Hour=hour(datetime),
          Minute=minute(datetime),
          second_Cut=cut(second(df$datetime),c(0,30,60),include.lowest = T),
          TEMP)][,
                 .(Avg=mean(TEMP)),by=.(Hour,Minute,second_Cut)]
res
```

This is the input data. BTW, you'd better provide the data file (such as csv file) rather than a screenshot.

[image: Raw data]

This is the output you want.

[image: output data]

as you see, I run this

```
library(data.table)
# generate random sample
tmp = seq(as.POSIXct("2023-03-05 12:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2023-03-07 12:12:00"),by="sec") 
df = data.table(datetime=tmp,TEMP=37+rnorm(length(tmp),sd = 2)) 
# this is what you what
res= df[,
        .(Hour=hour(datetime),
          Minute=minute(datetime),
          second_Cut=cut(second(df$datetime),c(0,30,60),include.lowest = T),
          TEMP)][,
                 .(Avg=mean(TEMP)),by=.(Hour,Minute,second_Cut)]
res
```

there is output
[image]

Comment: Thankyou Ryan.  This code gives me the same result - because my data has multiple dates, I need the output separated by date as well as hour/min/sec.  When I changed dates in your tmp file to include multiple days  ie tmp = seq(as.POSIXct("2023-03-05 12:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2023-03-07 12:12:00"),by="sec")
df = data.table(datetime=tmp,TEMP=37+rnorm(length(tmp),sd = 2)) and run the code the output gave only average temp for a single 24 hour period.

Comment: I added Date=date(datetime) into your code and it seems to work but I am getting these  Warning messages:
1: In as.data.table.list(jval, .named = NULL) :
  Item 1 has 54 rows but longest item has 173521; recycled with remainder.
2: In as.data.table.list(jval, .named = NULL) :
  Item 2 has 54 rows but longest item has 173521; recycled with remainder.
3: In as.data.table.list(jval, .named = NULL) :
  Item 3 has 54 rows but longest item has 173521; recycled with remainder.
4: In as.data.table.list(jval, .named = NULL) :
  Item 5 has 54 rows but longest item has 173521; recycled

Comment: @JMc  Are you sure? I run with the `tmp = seq(as.POSIXct("2023-03-05 12:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2023-03-07 12:12:00"),by="sec") df = data.table(datetime=tmp,TEMP=37+rnorm(length(tmp),sd = 2))` .  the output is the mutiple average temp, shown as the answer.

Comment: @JMc Where do you add `Date=date(datetime)`?

Comment: aveCT <-  cortemp5[,
                   .(Date= date(datetime),
                     Hour=hour(datetime),
                     Minute=minute(datetime),
                     second_Cut=cut(second(cortemp5$datetime),c(0,30,60),include.lowest = T),
                     CorTemp)][,
                               .(Avg=mean(CorTemp)),by=.(Date,Hour,Minute,second_Cut)]
aveCT

Comment: dput (AveCT) [2290:2300]

Comment: Date Hour Minute second_Cut      Avg
2022-12-11   16      7     [0,30] 38.14000
2022-12-11   16      7    (30,60] 38.09500
2022-12-11   16     10     [0,30] 38.07667
2022-12-11   16     10    (30,60] 38.07000
2022-12-11   16     11     [0,30] 38.05000
2022-12-11   16     11    (30,60] 38.07000
2022-12-12    5     29     [0,30] 37.99000
2022-12-12    5     29    (30,60] 37.98000
2022-12-12    5     57    (30,60] 38.21000
2022-12-12    5     58     [0,30] 38.21333
2022-12-12    5     58    (30,60] 38.21500
2022-12-12    5     59     [0,30] 38.21333

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df[, .(avg = mean(TEMP)), by = .(interval = floor_date(datetime, "30 seconds"))]
```

**results**

```
               interval    avg
 1: 2023-03-05 12:00:00 37.541
 2: 2023-03-05 12:00:30 36.803
 3: 2023-03-05 12:01:00 36.575
 4: 2023-03-05 12:01:30 37.515
 5: 2023-03-05 12:02:00 36.781
 6: 2023-03-05 12:02:30 37.105
 7: 2023-03-05 12:03:00 36.899
 8: 2023-03-05 12:03:30 37.074
 9: 2023-03-05 12:04:00 37.005
10: 2023-03-05 12:04:30 37.255
11: 2023-03-05 12:05:00 36.692
12: 2023-03-05 12:05:30 36.948
13: 2023-03-05 12:06:00 36.427
14: 2023-03-05 12:06:30 36.950
15: 2023-03-05 12:07:00 37.132
16: 2023-03-05 12:07:30 36.657
17: 2023-03-05 12:08:00 36.715
18: 2023-03-05 12:08:30 37.390
19: 2023-03-05 12:09:00 36.878
20: 2023-03-05 12:09:30 36.919
21: 2023-03-05 12:10:00 36.994
22: 2023-03-05 12:10:30 37.043
23: 2023-03-05 12:11:00 37.085
24: 2023-03-05 12:11:30 36.526
25: 2023-03-05 12:12:00 38.293
```

**data** *same as in Ryan's answer*

```
tmp = seq(as.POSIXct("2023-03-05 12:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2023-03-05 12:12:00"),by="sec")
df = data.table(datetime=tmp,TEMP=37+rnorm(length(tmp),sd = 2))
```

Comment: Thank you.  That works too and separates by date - awesome.

Comment: > cortemp5[, .(avg = mean(CorTemp)), by = .(interval = floor_date(datetime, "30 seconds"))]
                 interval      avg
   1: 2022-12-10 10:29:00 37.02000
   2: 2022-12-10 10:29:30 37.05333
   3: 2022-12-10 10:30:00 37.07333
   4: 2022-12-10 10:30:30 37.10000
   5: 2022-12-10 10:31:00 37.14000
  ---                             
4504: 2022-12-13 12:02:00 38.27333
4505: 2022-12-13 12:03:00 38.31500
4506: 2022-12-13 12:03:30 38.34000
4507: 2022-12-13 12:04:00 38.39000
4508: 2022-12-13 12:04:30 38.39500